# Can't get NHibernate and Log4Net to generate logging.

Tags: nhibernate, logging, log4net

I can't get any logging of NHibernate or my application. I tried EVERYTHING that I could think about, but nothing works!

Here is my code:

```
using System.Reflection;
using NHibernate.Cfg;

[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Log4Net.config", Watch = true)]
namespace NHibernate_Log4Net
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cfg = new Configuration()
                    .Configure()
                    .AddAssembly(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
        }
    }
}



namespace NHibernate_Log4Net.Model
{
    public class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Title { get; set; }
        public int Alias { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Item.hbm.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="NHibernate_Log4Net.Model.Item" assembly="NHibernate_Log4Net" auto-import="false">
  <class name="User" table="Users">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="Native"/>
    </id>

    <property name="Title" length="255" not-null="true" />
    <property name="Alias" length="255" not-null="true" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Log4Net.config file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<log4net debug="false">

  <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="log4netLogger.log" />
    <appendToFile value="false" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="1000KB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="OutputDebugStringAppender" type="log4net.Appender.OutputDebugStringAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%-5p %m - %c -%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="TraceAppender" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date - %message%newline"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="OutputDebugStringAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="TraceAppender" />
  </root>
  <logger name="NHibernate" additivity="false">
    <level value="FATAL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="OutputDebugStringAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="TraceAppender" />
  </logger>
  <logger name="NHibernate.SQL" additivity="false">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
  </logger>
  <!-- 
      NHibernate.Loader.Loader logs diagnostic stuff and SELECTs. 
      You can use either logger, or both, depending on you needs.
    -->
  <logger name="NHibernate.Loader.Loader" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
  </logger>


</log4net>
```

NHibernate throws an error that the class `Users` doesn't exist. This is expected, but why do I not see any logging from this, from NHibernate?

(I can log it myself, but the point that I can't see any log from NHibernate).

Answer (score 0):

The config file needs to match the executable, is your executable named Log4Net.exe?

Comment: My executable name is NHibernate_Log4Net.exe but the Log4Net.config is not the app.config, but it's used in [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Log4Net.config", Watch = true)].

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to load it for you. Try to name it NHibernate_Log4Net.exe.config instead.

Comment: I tried, it doesn't do anything. and as I said above I don't think it is needed.

Comment: Did you try putting the attribute in your AssemblyInfo.cs file instead of in the main class?  I wonder if it has to do with where the attribute is being declared?

Comment: Thanks, but this don't work too. Also if I omit the XmlConfgurator, some people says that is should work, but nothing that I did seems to work...

Comment: Have you tried absolutely referencing the log4net.config.  It seems like it isn't finding the file at all.  Also, hvae you tried turning on log4net's debugging feature? http://log4net.sourceforge.net/release/1.2.0.30316/doc/manual/faq.html#internalDebug

Comment: Thanks. You right, the config path wasn't found. Now I can get log from log4net, but nothing from NHibernate...

Answer (score 0):

I have had trouble using the XmlConfigurator attribute in the past.  Perhaps you should just call XmlConfigurator explicitly in your main like so:

```
namespace NHibernate_Log4Net
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo("log4net.config"));
            var cfg = new Configuration()
                    .Configure()
                    .AddAssembly(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://web.archive.org/web/20110514164829/http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/07/01/how-to-configure-log4net-for-use-with-nhibernate.aspx

I used the above link to set up logging. Try the following

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Log4Net.config", Watch = true)]
namespace NHibernate_Log4Net
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            var cfg = new Configuration()
                    .AddAssembly(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
                    .Configure()

        }
    }
}
```

The extra is this line

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

It didnt work for me till I added that. I know this is somewhat similar to what Jeffery suggested, but... just my 2cents.

Also, shouldnt the Configure() call on the Nhibernate configuration object come last? After the Assembly is added?

Comment: I can get logging from log4net, but I don't see any log from NHibernate. from what I know the configuration come first, and it mean that we first configure based on the xml configuratio file and then we looking for the hbm files.

Answer (score 0):

If the logging levels set for the NHibernate loggers are too high (or off), you may not see any log messages from NHibernate. For example, what is the value of 
`((log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger)LogManager.GetLogger("NHibernate").Logger).Level`?

You should have a section in your config file like this:

```
<log4net>
        <appender name="NHLog" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
                <file value="logs/nhibernate.log" />
                <appendToFile value="false" />
                <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                        <conversionPattern value="%d{HH:mm:ss.fff} [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n"  />
                </layout>
        </appender>
        <logger name="NHibernate" additivity="false">
                <level value="DEBUG"/>
                <appender-ref ref="NHLog"/>
        </logger>
</log4net>
```

**Update:** If the log file is always created (when non-existent before a run) but is always empty, this points to an exception during appending. To minimise the possibility of an exception, have a very simple `conversionPattern` (perhaps just `"%m%n"`) and see if any output is generated. If there is, add back elements of the conversion pattern until you find where the problem is. If no output is generated, log something to the NHibernate logger from your own code (this is perfectly OK) and step through it in the debugger.

```
ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("NHibernate");

log.Info("Application starting");
```

If still no joy, you may have to post some of your code/configuration.

Comment: I have, and the logs/nhibernate.log is always generated but remain empty.